# How to calculate the listbox scrollbar row based on the thumb position?

Tags: c++, winapi

While searching about I found these topics by `Raymond Chen` [position calculation in scroll bars](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090921-00/?p=16653) and [scrollbar series](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030725-00/?p=43053) I have read all the series but I still couldn't figure out how to properly calculate it, I'm not sure if I have missed something as English is a bit difficult to me.

Based on what i read, I tried to calculate it like this:

1- Get the ***total height*** of the list box `range max * row height`

2- Get the ***scroll area*** `listbox height - arrows - thumb height`

3- How many ***pixels*** of the total height must be scrolled for each pixel of the 'scroll area' `total height/scroll area`

4- Resulting in the formula:

`((thumb position - arrow) * pixels) / row height`

To get the thumb position I have used the API [GetScrollBarInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollbarinfo), however, it return the thumb position in a different position than where it was, in the example below it returned 45 while it's at 40:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUKaO.png)

My calc method returned 408 while the top row is 406.

I know about the APIs [SetScrollInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setscrollinfo), [GetScrollInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollinfo) and [GetScrollBarInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollbarinfo), however, as i mentioned they return a different position than where the thumb really was and new data (rows) is constantly added to the control im working, making not viable calling these api multiple times.

How do windows calculate the listbox top row relative to the thumb position? im looking for information to create a custom scrollbar.

Comment: Why worry about how Windows does it? If you're writing a custom scrollbar you can do it however you want to do it.

Comment: One thing, it only makes sense to scroll the part that is currently off-screen. That is, if your list has 50 items but the screen only shows 40, your SB range should only be for the ten that are off-screen, not the 50 that make up the entire list.

Comment: Do you need to dynamically change the size of the slider? The more the number, the smaller the slider?

Comment: -Jonathan Potter but i need to know the position of the rows relative to the thumb position, or how i would know to which row scroll when i scroll my custom scrollbar? -SoronelHaetir sorry but i dont understand what you mean @JunjieZhu-MSFT no i dont.

Comment: HI, @Cesar. I followed up on your question in [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/814726/how-to-get-scrollbar-thumb-position.html?childToView=840848#comment-840848).